# Is there a language with non-isomorphic minimum-state UFAs?

Tags: finite-automata, nondeterminism

For all regular languages L, by the [Myhill-Nerode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) classes, all state-minimal [DFAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization) for L are isomorphic. ​ On the other hand, "[a regular language may have many non-isomorphic state-minimal nfas](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397515002625)". ​ What about [Unambiguous Finite Automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unambiguous_finite_automaton)? ​ Every DFA is also a UFA, so every regular language has at least one UFA. ​ The natural numbers are well-ordered, so in turn every regular language has at least one state-minimal UFA.

Is there a regular language whose state-minimal [Unambiguous Finite Automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unambiguous_finite_automaton) are not all isomorphic to each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In their [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220530733_A_note_about_minimal_non-deterministic_automata) "A note about minimal non-deterministic automata" Arnold, Dicky and Nivat observe that the problem of finding non-isomorphic minimal automata was solved in a report by Christian Carrez (Lille, 1970).

They give the following example, which happen to be both unambiguous, so are applicable in your case too.

[image: isomorphic nondet finite automata]

Comment: Do you know whether-or-not there's also an example for a 1-symbol alphabet? ​ ​

Comment: A very nice example for a one-symbol alphabet was just added to a similar question at our cousin site cstheory: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/36824/12122

Comment: That example's NFA is not unambiguous. ​ (Consider the length-1 input.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Sorry. You are right of course. I forgot about your restriction! It still is a nice example, but not at this point.