# Does for every NFA $N$ exist NFA $M$ that has maximum 3 final states and $L(N) = L(M)$

Tags: automata, finite-automata, nondeterminism

I have a question:

Does for every NFA $N$ exist NFA $M$ that has maximum 3 final states and $L(N) = L(M)$.
I can answer no for DFA for below language and its minimal DFA that has 4 final states .

$L_1 = \{ax_1,bx_2,cx_3,dx_4 | x_1 \in \Sigma^* ,x_2 \in (a+b)^*,x_3 \in (b+c)^* ,x_4 \in (a+b+c)^*\}$ , $\Sigma = \{a,b,c,d\}$

but because there isn't any specific algorithm for finding minimal NFA,I don't know how to answer this question.can any one help ? it seems that answer is no.

Comment: There is no such thing as a minimal NFA, well it is not unique.

Comment: Why be so modest? I think at most two final states for an NFA will work.

Comment: @HendrikJan: Do you think that 2 final state for NFA is enough?how can you say when you don't know NFA minimal?

Comment: There is a unique minimal DFA for every regular language, but there are possibly [structurally different](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/64912) minimal NFA.

Comment: I think if we can say a regular language that its minimal NFA has 4 final states,so we can prove this.

Comment: @HendrikJan Or even just one...

Comment: what is the answer for NFAs that doesn't have any $\lambda$-transition?

Comment: @Yuval I believe that without $\varepsilon$-transitions the empty string has to get its own final state when it belongs to the language. So two final states in that case.

Comment: @HendrikJan Right.

Comment: @xavierm02: I think you missed the word "final" in the question (and its title).